# Images won't load in flask in static folder

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flask

I'm trying to load two images into my html when the 'next' button is clicked. Before I tried to connect all of my front end to flask, it worked fine. The css and js files are working just fine, but the images won't load. What happens is when the button is pressed, the js swaps out the old html in the main div with the new, which contains images (you can see this in the update() function). All of the js, css and images are in the static folder. Any help would be appreciated. Edit: extra info: It's throwing a 404 error saying it cannot locate the images in a folder called Images, even though I'm not asking it to look for them in that, I'm only asking it to look in the static folder. github repo: https://github.com/ewanh26/Web-App
Code:

```
main.py:

from flask import *
    
app = Flask(__name__)
    
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

index.js:

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    let pageCounter = 0;
    let maxPages = 5

    const $prevButton = document.getElementById('prev')
    const $nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
    const $div = document.getElementById('maindiv')

    function update() {    
        switch (pageCounter) {
            default:
                $div.className = 'slide1Header';
                $($div).html("<h1>THE WORLD OF TOMORROW. WHAT'S NEXT FOR US?</h1>");
                break;
            case 1:
                $div.className = 'slide2';
                $($div).html(`
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='starry.jpg') }}" alt="stars" id="starimg">
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='moon.png') }}" alt="moon" id="moonimg">
                `);
                break;
        }
    }

    update();

    $prevButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (pageCounter > 0) {
            pageCounter--;
            console.log(pageCounter);
            update();
        }
    });
    $nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (pageCounter < maxPages) {
            pageCounter++;
            console.log(pageCounter);
            update();
        }
    });

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        document.body.style.setProperty('--scroll', window.pageYOffset / (document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight));
    });

style.css
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    html, body {
        font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .slide1Header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: fixed;
        font-style: italic;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(-45deg,
        #bd33c4,
        #DE498E, 
        #FF5F58, 
        #FC9144, 
        #f8c330e1, 
        #FBAB19, 
        #FD9301, 
        #FE4A2B, 
        #FF0055
        );
        background-size: 2000% 2000%;
        animation: backgroundChange 15s ease infinite;
        transform: none;
    }
    .slide2 {
        background: black;
    }
    #starimg {
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

    }
    #moonimg {
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        top: 17px;
        right: 33%;
        left: 66%;
        position: absolute;
        filter: brightness(5);
        filter: contrast(0);
        filter: blur(0.7px);
        filter: opacity(0.95);
        animation: moonScroll 0.5s linear infinite;
        animation-play-state: paused;
        animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -1s);
        transform: rotate(-40deg);
        transform-origin: 0px 500px;
    }
    #moonimg::before {
        transform: rotate(-30deg);
    }
    button.prev, button.next {
        border-radius: 8px;
        position: fixed;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        border-color: white;
        border-style: none;
        padding: 4pt;
    }
    button.prev {
        left: 5%;
        bottom: 5%;
    }
    button.next {
        right: 5%;
        bottom: 5%;
    }
    .prev:hover, .next:hover, .prev:focus, .next:focus {
        background-color: #ff245b;
        color: white;
        outline: none;
    }
    @keyframes backgroundChange {
        0% {
            background-position: 0 50%;
        }
        50% {
            background-position: 100% 50%;
        }
        100% {
            background-position: 0 50%;
        }
    }
    @keyframes moonScroll {
        from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }
    }

index.html
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
            <!--<link rel="preload" as="image" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='starry.jpg') }}">
            <link rel="preload" as="image" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='moon.png') }}">!-->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <title>The Future</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="maindiv"></div>
            <button class="prev" id="prev">&larr; Previous</button>
            <button class="next" id="next">Next &rarr;</button>
            <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
        </body>
    </html>

index.js

    let pageCounter = 0;
    let maxPages = 5
    
    const $prevButton = document.getElementById('prev')
    const $nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
    const $div = document.getElementById('maindiv')
    
    function update() {    
        switch (pageCounter) {
            default:
                $div.className = 'slide1Header';
                $($div).html("<h1>THE WORLD OF TOMORROW. WHAT'S NEXT FOR US?</h1>");
                break;
            case 1:
                $div.className = 'slide2';
                $($div).html(`
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='starry.jpg') }}" alt="stars" id="starimg">
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='moon.png') }}" alt="moon" id="moonimg">
                `);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    update();
    
    $prevButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (pageCounter > 0) {
            pageCounter--;
            console.log(pageCounter);
            update();
        }
    });
    $nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (pageCounter < maxPages) {
            pageCounter++;
            console.log(pageCounter);
            update();
        }
    });
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        document.body.style.setProperty('--scroll', window.pageYOffset / (document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight));
    });
```

Comment: your code block is kind of messed up, could you please fix that first so it is better to read?

Comment: @shiny there u go

Comment: are your images in the same folder as your js and css files?

Comment: @shiny yeah they are

Comment: @shiny check the github repo if u need to know where stuff is properly

Comment: @shiny It's throwing a 404 error saying it cannot locate the images in a folder called Images, even though I'm not asking it to look for them in that, I'm only asking it to look in the static folder. just extra info

Comment: i would gladly have a look, sadly i'm getting a 404 on that github link

Comment: @shiny oh its private hold on

Comment: @shiny should be good now

Comment: @shiny I literally just did a test app and images loaded fine! This is annoying me so much

Comment: @shiny i hardcoded the images directly into the html and it worked, so there's something up with the js?

Comment: is your js function directly in the index html or in a seperate file you are loading in? 
Try to compare your link you've put yourself in the file with the one generated by url_for

Comment: @shiny separate file, and what do u mean?

Comment: @shiny got it to work finally! just used the actual path (/static/imagename) thanks for the enthusiasm to help tho :)

Comment: i've meant, when you have a look at the generated page on the image url. What url is generated by url_for, when you load your index.html and look at image link in the html code

Comment: @shiny , before it created the url Images/imgname but it works now because instead of creating an url i just referenced it's actual location (/static/imgname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it myself just by using the normal file path rather than creating a url with url_for() in the javascript file.